# How to iterate across Ansible inventory whilst referencing hostvars in add_host

Tags: ansible

I want to dynamically create an in-memory inventory which is a filter of a standard inventory including only the host where a specific service is installed.  The filtered inventory is to be used in a subsequent play.

So I identify the IP address of the host where the service is installed.

```
- name: find where the service is installed
  win_service:
    name: "{{ service }}"
  register: service_info
```

This returns a boolean 'exists' value.  Using this value as a condition an attempt to add the host where the service is running is made.

```
- name: create filtered in memory inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ ansible_host }}"
  when: service_info.exists
```

The add_host module bypasses the play host loop and only runs once for all the hosts in the play, as such this only works if the host that add_host runs against is the one that has the service installed.

Below is an attempt to force add_host to iterate across the hosts in the inventory however it appears that the hostvars and therefore service_info.exists are not being passed through to add_host and therefore the conditional 'when' check always returns false.

```
- name: create filtered in memory inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ ansible_host }}"
  when: service_info.exists
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"
```

Is there a way to pass the hosts with their hostvars to add_host as a iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a tasks before `add_host` to create a temporary file on executor with the list of server matching the condition, and then looping in module `add_host` over the file.

example taken from [Improving use of add_host in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338376/improving-use-of-add-host-in-ansible) that I asked before

```
---
- hosts: servers
  tasks:

   - name: find where the service is installed
     win_service:
       name: "{{ service }}"
     register: service_info

   - name: write server name in file on control node
     lineinfile:
       path: /tmp/servers_foo.txt
       state: present
       line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
     when: service_info.exists

   - name: assign target to group
     add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       groups:
         - foo
     with_lines: cat /tmp/servers_foo.txt
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```